# Proof the 1 language is contained in another

Tags: elementary-set-theory, formal-languages, regular-expressions

Does anyone know what the best method is to prove that the intersection of Language1 and Language 2 = Language1?

Where both languages are over alphabet {a,b,c}.

Comment: Prove that any word $w$ which is in $L_1$ is also in $L_2$.  If this is not enough help you will need to post a specific problem, together with your attempts at solving it.  You don't want people telling you lots of really basic stuff which you understand already.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of equality of two regular expression is EXPSACE-complete. So I guess building the automaton and working on the automaton would be the easier way to solve your problem.